# hmatrix installation error on OS X 10.9.4

Tags: haskell, cabal, hmatrix

Is anyone successfully using hmatrix-0.16.0.4 on OSX 10.9?

I get the following error:

```
Prelude> import Numeric.LinearAlgebra
Prelude Numeric.LinearAlgebra> let m = (3><4) [1..] :: Matrix Double
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package primitive-0.5.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package vector-0.10.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.5.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package binary-0.5.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package old-locale-1.0.0.5 ... linking ... done.
Loading package time-1.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package random-1.0.1.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package split-0.2.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package storable-complex-0.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package hmatrix-0.16.0.4 ... linking ... <interactive>:
lookupSymbol failed in relocateSection (relocate external)
/Users/tba/.cabal/lib/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.6.3/hmatrix-0.16.0.4/libHShmatrix-0.16.0.4.a: unknown symbol `___ieee_divdc3'
ghc: unable to load package `hmatrix-0.16.0.4'
```

I installed using `brew install gsl && cabal install hmatrix`.
 My ghc version is 7.6.3.

I suspect it should be built with gcc (instead of clang) -- how can I change this?

[(GitHub ticket)](https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/issues/81)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by installing ghc 7.8. It's unfortunate that homebrew's "haskell-platform" is so out of date.